# How to center background image on a narrow screen vertically

Tags: css

I use an image as a backround, something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://somestorage.com/img.png" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;

}
.container img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is thought, that I wanna have a central top part on narrow screens. Now it shrinks like this:
[image]

I wanna it be like here:
[image]

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/jw2xonge/25/)

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: does the user need to be able to scroll back and forth across the image or do you want it cropped?

Comment: it should be cropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I changed `min-width: 100%;` with `width: 100%;` and added `object-fit: cover;`

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.ohandroid.com/android/TJ0mc.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;

}
.container img {
  min-width: 720px;
  min-height: 480px;
}
```

You could also change out the images for differing sizes of screens using media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/background-mobile.jpg);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/background-tablet.jpg);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/background-desktop.jpg);
   }
}
```

ref: https://web.dev/optimize-css-background-images-with-media-queries/